# CloudWatch Event fails to invocate lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a lambda created by following [aws tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) on how to create a scheduler to trigger lambda.

I have checked several times to make sure the lambda has the suggested role properties that tutorial mentions with the scheduler and a permission to the scheduler. I have them all deployed as a stack via CloudFormation Template. Unfortunately I cannot share the CFT, you just have to trust me on this.

**I am looking for possible reasons that could cause what I see, which is on every invocation coming from CloudWatch Events there is an invocation error recorded on the monitoring tab of my lambda page.** Unfortunately nothing is being logged and I do not have CloudTrail enabled to have anyway to troubleshoot this via logs.

To sum up, stack has:

- Lambda function X
- CloudWatch Events scheduler to call function X every some minutes
- Permission to the scheduler to invoke lambda
- Lambda role

I cannot share the CFT but it is pretty much same as what [this blog](https://quocvu.github.io/2016/07/04/running-aws-lambda-on-schedule.html) mentions.

Comment: What happens when you try to invoke manually?

Comment: Manual invocation work fine.

Comment: Whats the output of `aws lambda get-policy --function-name <name>` for your function?

Comment: @BrandonMiller Unfortunately this is a restricted account and I would not be able to run that command with my user. I am basically looking for an answer which would list possible causes. I understand it requires trouble shooting, but I have limited access.

Comment: @Griffin you can't troubleshoot without access to the things you're trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: @Michael Vacuous truth. For that reason, as you read the question, looking for a list of possible causes.

Comment: @Griffin If you are restricted from running get-policy, are you sure you have the right permissions to create the lambda role/policy and the event permission? Have you tried to deploy your CFT in an account where you have root/admin access?

Comment: @KMo Stack is created successfully

Comment: Can you check the lambda logs and see what error is posted. You can see that at the log group "/aws/lambda/<lambda name>". If you do not find anything here, then ensure the permissions for lambda includes CW

Comment: @omuthu As I mentioned, "Unfortunately nothing is being logged".

Comment: If nothing is getting logged, does your lambda role have these permissions. "Action" : [ "logs:PutLogEvents", "logs:DescribeLogStreams", "logs:Create" ]. if not, include this to get the error getting logged. Additionally, in the code add debug statements at various checkpoints to track it better

Comment: @omuthu, It does have the permissions for logging. No lambda code is being executed, it doesn't even get there. The event fails to invoke lambda every single interval.

Comment: Can you delete the trigger from lambda and re-add the cloudwatch event schedule trigger again. Looks to me something if the invoke Lambda permission has some issue

Comment: preferably add the trigger from Lambda end and not from the CW console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was resolved after it was found that the role assumed by lambda did not have logging permission due to typo mistake which was masking the underlying errors.

After fixing the logging issue it was clear that the invocation errors where due to restrictions on the role assumed by lambda.